# ... часть написана(,) и сказано, что

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли-с запятая?

`Но там же – в classroom – то только теоретическая часть написана(,) и сказано, что надо написать мини-конспект, сделав какие-то задания (насчёт которых я и-с спрашиваю).`

Comment: Наверное, задумывалось так: «_Но там же — **в classroom-то**  — только теоретическая часть_…»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Но там же – в classroom – то только теоретическая **часть написана** и **сказано**, что надо написать мини-конспект, сделав какие-то задания (насчёт которых я и-с спрашиваю).*

Запятая не ставится, **общим элементом** является обстоятельство места. Союз И связывает **две предикативные** основы:  (1) часть написана и (2) *сказано*.

Comment: Просто я подумал, что там может быть ваше так называемое «противопоставление».

Comment: Где здесь можно увидеть противопоставление? Противительный союз НО в начале предложения? Но это присоединительный союз, относится к контексту.  Но мне пришлось задуматься над этим предложением по другому поводу...